# How to enable "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" through PowerShell (Azure CLI)?

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell, firewall, azure-cli

After creating a new Azure SQL server using `az sql server create`, how can I enable the following options through PowerShell(Azure CLI)?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's in the documentation for Azure SQL somewhere, if you search for "azure sql firewall allow azure services", but here's what you need to do - create a rule with a start and end address of 0.0.0.0, like this:

```
az sql server firewall-rule create --resource-group <resource group name> --server <azure sql name> -n <any name> --start-ip-address 0.0.0.0 --end-ip-address 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: This seems to enable that option. Thanks!

Comment: It's in the API docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/firewallrules/createorupdate

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Scott answer, the equivalent way to do this in the [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-4.4.0) module is:

```
New-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -FirewallRuleName <fw-rule-name> -StartIpAddress '0.0.0.0' -EndIpAddress '0.0.0.0' -ServerName <sql-server-name> -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name>
```

Comment: Do you know what to do when you have "Deny public access" to Yes. Then you can't configure firewall rules.

Answer (score 2):

my small contribution here.

the below az command with the respective group and sqlservername sets "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" to Yes

az sql server firewall-rule create -g  -s  -n AllowAllWindowsAzureIps --start-ip-address 0.0.0.0 --end-ip-address 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new rule with specific name (**AllowAllWindowsAzureIps**);

```
New-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroup> -ServerName <serverName> -FirewallRuleName "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps" -StartIpAddress "0.0.0.0" -EndIpAddress "0.0.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this and I believe it's doable via the following script now...

```
New-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroup> -ServerName <SQLServerName> -AllowAllAzureIPs
```

Answer (score -1):

```
az sql server firewall-rule create --resource-group <resource group name> --server <azure sql name> -n <any name> --start-ip-address 0.0.0.0 --end-ip-address 0.0.0
```

this command will open up the server for all the world. From a security perspective, it is not ok. But the question was in opening the server just for Azure services.

Comment: This only changes that setting flag, it won't open up the server to everyting, right?
(Or is the `-end-ip-address 0.0.0` not a typo?)