# Power apps Azure AD login failed for other users

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, powerapps

I am new to Azure, and Power apps.

I have made an app that functions exactly as I wanted...for myself.

I shared the app with others at my company, and while they can open and interact with the app itself, when they go to a page that is supposed to list all the records from an Azure SQL database it shows nothing.

I observed the issues in the monitor for Power Apps, and it is saying:
"Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'.\r\nclientRequestId:"

[This gallery should have items listed]    (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTozk.png)

[View I have from my account.]    (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuK3T.png)
[Error message]    (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FavrT.png)

I have the database setup to use AAD, and the users are all on our account and a part of AD. I tried adding the AAD connection to the app, and while it has the users authenticate (successfully), it still will not show the data. [PA Monitor log] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCMJ9.png)

I have tried removing and readding the connections.
I have tried to access it from several different accounts.

I am a global admin for our account and have owner permission through AD.

I have no idea what the issue is, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is your DB also located in Azure server? You have to check the permission status in DB configuration. There was a function "Allow Azure services and resources access to this server" which should be checked or unchecked I don't remember exactly.

Comment: Yea, its an Azure SQL server, and I do have that box ticked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the "Unauthorized" error in your screenshot, it looks like the permissions might be missing for the users in the Azure SQL database. Since the users are accessing the database through your application, you need to make sure that the IP address access is granted. If you want any IP to be able to [connect to the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-firewall-rule-azure-sql-database?view=azure-sqldw-latest) you can [set IP firewall rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58449069/how-to-enable-allow-azure-services-and-resources-to-access-this-server-through) or Go to Azure Portal > Azure SQL > your server > Set server firewall rule (Networking section) > and check "Allow Azure Services and resources to access this server." (This might end up being more permissions than needed for your scenario though, so if this is the case you may need to set up more fine-tuned access.)

You also need to make sure that the permissions for the users are allowed under Access control (IAM) , and that the app permissions are allowed under App Registration > API permissions

If you still run into this issue, the Power Apps monitor logs should show some additional details.

Comment: I have the box checked to allow Azure services. 

For IAM, what role should they be set at? I have set the users to ‘reader’, and ‘contributor’.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I FINALLY solved this problem.

The issue was that I needed to add the users to the database itself with Azure data studio. I had done this already, but apparently, it takes a few minutes to update, so when I tried and tested that, it wasn't working.

So what I did was add my Azure AD group to the database with 'db_datareader' & 'db_datawriter' permissions, and now everything works fine!

Thanks for the pointers everyone.